# Error de E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection Código de proveedor 17002

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo un problemas con mi base de datos local, lo que sucede es que quiero conectarme a mi bd pero pero me aparece este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El estatus me regresa lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Ya hice de todo para poder solucionarse, desde crear otro listener usando el netcat, ejecutando el comando lsnrctl en cmd y ninguno, espero y puedan ayudarme por favor, con el sqlplus si me conecto bien, el problema aqui es hacerlo desde el sql developer, quedo al pendiente de sus comentarios, saludos

---

si comprendo con lo de las imagenes y si tendré cuidado para la proxima XD  pude solucionarlo reinstalando todo de nuevo, se instaló todo pero me apareció el mismo error, despues lo que hice fue ejecutar el comando netca para crear otro LISTENER, previamente lo eliminé y lo creé, después pidió un nombre, aqui lo que hice fue poner un nombre por ejm LISTENER1 y se creo con normalidad, despues volvi a hacer una prueba y si se conectó, seguí los pasos de este video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=na81f7ADrOM&t=120s
Espero y a alguien le sirva, saludos

---

que creen, cambio de planes, volvió a tronar y la solución que puse arriba puede no funcionar, alguna otra sugerencia? No sé si a ciencia se acierta pero igual corrijanme si estoy mal, noté que después que se suspende mi equipo (mi laptop) y despues que vuelvo a trabajar con la lap ya me aparece el error? Creen que eso afecte y cause este error?

Comment: ¿Se está ejecutando el servicio del _listener_?  ¿qué te devuelve el comando `lsnrctl status`? ¿El contenido de tu `listner.ora`?

Comment: Hola, ya actualicé mi pregunta, saludos

Comment: No pegues imágenes que contienen texto, cuando puedes pegar el texto en si.
Creo que el mensaje de error que se ve en la salida del comando es suficiente para orientarse. ¿El Host `192.168.1.67` responde al ping? ¿Tiene abierto el puerto? ¿Hay firewalls de por medio?

Comment: Hola jaschguate, comprendo lo que dices y si quedó todo validado y en cuando a lo de los puertos no  hay nada de eso ya que hice la instalación tal cual, pero aun asi marcaba ese error, en un rato mas pondré una posible solución como respuesta, probablemente a alguien le sirva, aunque no estoy seguro si a futuro persista el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

la solución que pueden hacer es poner en el hostname "localhost", ya que si se pone una dirección por ejm 192.00.11.222 ocurrirá este error no he investigado la razón por la cual ocurre este problema, yo cambié a localhost y hasta la fecha no me ha causado problemas, esto se cambia en el archivo listener.ora y el tnsnames.ora y por ultimo reiniciar el oracle, espero y les funcione, saludos

Comment: Aunque ha pasado mucho tiempo: ¡no olvides aceptar la respuesta que te ha sido más útil!

Answer (score 0):

mi solución a este problema fue reiniciar el servicio de OracleServiceXE.
[image: Seleccionar servicio y reiniciarlo.]

También puede pasar que no se inicie automáticamente, en ese caso lo pueden configurar para que se inicie automáticamente. Esto haciendo click derecho - propiedades, ahi verán la opción del inicio.

PD: Para acceder a ese listado de servicios deben, en el buscado de aplicaciones de windows buscar "Servicios"
[image: servicios]
Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

logre realizar la conexion para sqlserver usando mtls en windows, primero segui los pasos del sitio de oracle para establecer una nueva conexión:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/serverless/adbsb/connect-sql-dev182.html#GUID-14217939-3E8F-4782-BFF2-021199A908FD

posteriormente agrega la contraseña al usuario admin de tu base de datos debido a que sqlserver no permite la conexión si el campo de contraseña se deja vacío:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35199084/forgot-oracle-username-and-password-how-to-retrieve

Te dejo una captura con un ejemplo de mi conexión:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El idioma del sitio es el Español, por favor traduce tu respuesta. ;)